# Typescript adds additional "or ( | ) " when I add : | undefined to interface in React Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an issue which I cannot figure or google-out.
I declare such initial values of context.

```
export const LineSectionsContext = createContext<LineSectionsContextValues>({
    lineSectionsDefectsDetailsData: undefined,
    lineSectionsWarningsDetailsData: undefined,
});
```

This is how I define interface LineSectionsContextValues:

```
interface LineSectionsContextValues {
    lineSectionsDefectsDetailsData:LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType | undefined;
    lineSectionsWarningsDetailsData:LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsTyp | undefined;
}
```

And here strange behaviour starts, when I hit ctrl+s interface syntax is automatically changed, it adds automatically typescript "or" syntax, which is |
:

[image]

This is how type is defined:

```
export type LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType = {
    id: string;
    timestamp: Date;
    type: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    lineId: string;
    kilometer: number;
    coordinates: [];
    description: string;
};
```

When I add different type it works well.
Can You please let me know how to fix it ?
I got a feedback on code review that syntax of interface should be :
lineSectionsDefectsDetailsData : LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType | undefined;

Comment: This is not a feature of a programming language, nor a library. You have a linter or formatter that formats the code on save. Change the linter/formatter settings your project uses. Or if editor has special linter/formatter that others in your team don't have, then you probably need to disable or tune it.

Comment: In addition to what @VLAZ said, the additional Union token doesn't change the behavior of the code. In the AST it is still just one UnionType with a collection of `LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType` and `undefined`

Comment: The behavior is not changing, just the formatting

Comment: The behavior seems to be like the extra comma at the end of a list which helps diffs stay on a single line as new items are added

Comment: As @VLAZ said that's most likely due to your editor configuration, nothing to do with your code. You have it set to auto-format on save and have an extension installed such as Eslint/Prettier/Beautify